# two dimensional arraylists and input/sorting

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am trying to add all the doubles between two `<end>` instances into an arraylist within an arraylist (at each index of `<end>` have the doubles between the `<end>`s, and so forth)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> myArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
int j = 0;
int nLine = 0;

    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.next();

        //System.out.println(line);
        if(!line.equals("<end>")) {
            nLine = Double.valueOf(line);
            ArrayList<Double> row = new ArrayList<Double>();
            myArr.add(row);


            row.add(j, nLine);
            j=j++;

        } else {
            j=j++;
        }
    }
```

As it stands now the code is putting in a single double in a an array (as opposed to all of the ones between  statements; thus the output looks like this:
[[1.4], [3], [15], [3.2], etc. etc.

where I want it to look like this:
[[1.4, 3, 15, 3.2], [5, 13.4], [954.3, etc....

The file it is scanning is essentially:

```
<end>
1.4
3
15
3.2
<end>
5
13.4
<end>
954.3
43 etc. etc. (infinitely)
```

My goal (eventually) is to tally how many doubles are in each arrayList index and make sure none of the doubles are exactly the same, and to make sure each of the row arrays have no more than 10 values in them.
So I have been stuck and any help is appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, you're creating a new `ArrayList` every time line isn't equal to `"<end>"`--maybe you'd only want to create a new list every time it *is* `"<end>"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> myArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
int nLine = 0;

ArrayList<Double> currArr = null;

while(scan.hasNext()) {
    String line = scan.next();

    if(!line.equals("<end>")) {
        nLine = Integer.valueOf(line);

        currArr.add(nLine);
    } else {
        if(currArr!=null) myArr.add(currArr);

        currArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }
}

if(currArr!=null) myArr.add(currArr);
```

In the middle of the code you're using `Integer` instead of `Double`.  Not sure why so I left it.  Code assumes the input always starts with `<end>`.

Comment: This solution always misses the final Doubles (after the last <end>), however thank you for the logic, I am still very new to java and even (relatively to the scope of Java) simple solutions such as this are mini epiphanies.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would miss the last set of numbers.  The last line should handle that.

Comment: Ahh my apologies James! In my haste I missed your final line of code, and it does in fact work. Thank you for the response and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashSet as a way to keep track of the duplicates (or better yet use an ArrayList of Sets instead to avoid the extra data structure)

Here's an example of generating a random # of ArrayLists without dups:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();      
HashSet<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();

for(int x=0; x<3; x++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myArr.add(row);
    for(int y=0; y<3; y++) {
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(100);
        if(!duplicates.contains(randomInt)) {
            row.add(0,randomInt);
            duplicates.add(randomInt);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<myArr.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(myArr.get(i));
}
```